# Objective C - Core Text Find index at position?

Tags: objective-c, core-text, ctlineref

I am trying to get the index of the closest character to a point.

The code below works perfectly fine as ling as my text alignment is set to left, as soon as I chage it to right or center it gives me the wrong index. What would be the solution to consider the text alignment while getting closest index to a point?

```
CTLineRef line = (CTLineRef)[lines objectAtIndex:i];
index = CTLineGetStringIndexForPosition(line, point);
```

**EDIT:**

My text alignment is done by adding a paragraph style that has it's textAlignment setting to `kCTCenterTextAlignment`

Comment: hey aryaxt, how did you implement the solution given below? I assume it was something like "CTLineGetStringIndexForPosition(line, CGPointMake(origins[i].x + point.x, point.y));", but that doesn't work for me. Did you do it differently?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The point is relative to the line's origin (which changes with the alignment), so you have to use `CTFrameGetLineOrigins` and add the x value of the line's origin to your point's x value.

Comment: great answer as always, thanks. I was just curious how do u have so much knowledge about core text? Is there a specific project related to core text you've been working on?

Comment: I think the point is an absolute position, so we should subtract the x value of the line's origin from the point's x value? At least in my case it was subtraction.